# Is there a way to create multiple columns from existing columns of a dataframe in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I am trying to ingest an RDBMS table into Hive. I have obtained the dataframe in the following way:

```
val yearDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                                                   .option("dbtable", "(select * from schema.tablename where source_system_name='DB2' and period_year='2017') as year2017")
                                                   .option("user", devUserName)
                                                   .option("password", devPassword)
                                                   .option("numPartitions",15)
                                                   .load()
```

These are the columns of the dataframe:

```
geography:string|
project:string|
reference_code:string
product_line:string
book_type:string
cc_region:string
cc_channel:string
cc_function:string
pl_market:string
ptd_balance:double
qtd_balance:double
ytd_balance:double
xx_last_update_tms:timestamp
xx_last_update_log_id:int
xx_data_hash_code:string
xx_data_hash_id:bigint
```

The columns `ptd_balance, qtd_balance, ytd_balance` are double datatypes which are precision columns. Our project wants to convert their datatype from Double to String by creating new columns: `ptd_balance_text, qtd_balance_text, ytd_balance_text` with same data inorder to avoid any data truncation.

`withColumn` will create a new column in the dataframe.
`withColumnRenamed` will rename the existing column.

The dataframe has nearly 10 million records.
Is there an effective way to create multiple new columns with same data and different type from the existing columns in a dataframe ?

Comment: if any truncation is going to happen, it would have happened by the time you load it to a double column as per its precision. What's the point of casting it to a string later?

Comment: @philantrovert Oh, I didn't know that. In that case, how do I read the data directly into String ?

Comment: You're reading from a RDBMS and the datatype that you are getting here is according to your source table. If you want it as string, change the select clause in db_table argument to `cast(ptd_balance as string)` or `varchar` or whatever your rdbms supports.

Comment: @philantrovert Is this the way you suggest to read the table:
select geography,project,reference_code,product_line,book_type,cc_region,cc_channel, 
cc_function,pl_market,ptd_balance,qtd_balance,ytd_balance,xx_last_update_tms,
xx_last_update_log_id,xx_data_hash_code,xx_data_hash_id,
ptd_balance::character varying as 'ptd_balance_text', qtd_balance::character varying as 'qtd_balance_text', 
ytd_balance::character varying as 'ytd_balance_text'  from schema.tablename where period_year='2017'




I have given casting(::) to String (character varying in Greenplum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i was in your shoes, i would make changes in the extraction query or ask BI team to put some effort **:P** for adding and casting the fields on the fly while extracting, but any how what you are asking is possible.

You can add the columns from the existing columns as below. Check the `addColsTosampleDF` `dataframe`. I hope the comments below will be enough to understand, if you have any questions feel free to add in the comments and i will edit my answer.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SparkSession}

scala> val ss = SparkSession.builder().appName("TEST").getOrCreate()
18/08/07 15:51:42 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some configuration may not take effect.
ss: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@6de4071b

//Sample dataframe with int, double and string fields
scala> val sampleDf = Seq((100, 1.0, "row1"),(1,10.12,"col_float")).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
sampleDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: double ... 1 more field]

scala> sampleDf.printSchema
root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: double (nullable = false)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)

//Adding columns col1_string from col1 and col2_doubletostring from col2 with casting and alias
scala> val addColsTosampleDF = sampleDf.
select(sampleDf.col("col1"),
sampleDf.col("col2"),
sampleDf.col("col3"),
sampleDf.col("col1").cast("string").alias("col1_string"),
sampleDf.col("col2").cast("string").alias("col2_doubletostring"))
addColsTosampleDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: double ... 3 more fields]

//Schema with added columns
scala> addColsTosampleDF.printSchema
root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col2: double (nullable = false)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col1_string: string (nullable = false)
 |-- col2_doubletostring: string (nullable = false)

 scala> addColsTosampleDF.show()
+----+-----+---------+-----------+-------------------+
|col1| col2|     col3|col1_string|col2_doubletostring|
+----+-----+---------+-----------+-------------------+
| 100|  1.0|     row1|        100|                1.0|
|   1|10.12|col_float|          1|              10.12|
+----+-----+---------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: How about reading the RDBMS table directly:

select geography,project,reference_code,product_line,book_type,cc_region,cc_channel, cc_function,pl_market,ptd_balance,qtd_balance,ytd_balance,xx_last_update_tms, xx_last_update_log_id,xx_data_hash_code,xx_data_hash_id, ptd_balance::character varying as 'ptd_balance_text', qtd_balance::character varying as 'qtd_balance_text', ytd_balance::character varying as 'ytd_balance_text' from schema.tablename where period_year='2017'

As @philantrovert says, even before ingesting the data into Hive, data is already truncated while it is read into spark.

Comment: You can do the same thing in the JDBC select. I would suggest running the query first on the database and use it in the jdbc dataframe.

Comment: It is working. I just tested it for count and I got the number matching with the RDBMS table.

Comment: Ok, If you think my answer helped you to solve please tick the answer and upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this creating `query` from all `columns` like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType

//Input: 

scala> df.show
+----+-----+--------+--------+
|  id| name|  salary|   bonus|
+----+-----+--------+--------+
|1001|Alice| 8000.25|1233.385|
|1002|  Bob|7526.365| 1856.69|
+----+-----+--------+--------+


scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: double (nullable = false)
 |-- bonus: double (nullable = false)

//solution approach:
val query=df.columns.toList.map(cl=>if(cl=="salary" || cl=="bonus") col(cl).cast(StringType).as(cl+"_text") else col(cl))

//Output: 

scala> df.select(query:_*).printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary_text: string (nullable = false)
 |-- bonus_text: string (nullable = false)


scala> df.select(query:_*).show
+----+-----+-----------+----------+
|  id| name|salary_text|bonus_text|
+----+-----+-----------+----------+
|1001|Alice|    8000.25|  1233.385|
|1002|  Bob|   7526.365|   1856.69|
+----+-----+-----------+----------+
```